# Stopword Removal Dilemma

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stop-words

I am facing a dilemma with the stopwords function in NLTK. I am processing user-generated content from a social media platform by removing stopwords using NLTK. However, the dilemma is I want to keep personal pronouns in users' text, which are important for the classification task. These include words such as "I" "you" "we", etc.

Unfortunately, the stopwords function deletes these words, too, and I need them to be present. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you removing stop words in the first place?

Comment: nltk stopwords is nothing more than a set of strings. 
You can just create your own stopsords set. Even take a look in nltk stopwords and remove from there the one you want to keep

Comment: @OliverMason for a text classification task - I want to remove the unecessary words on an user's post apart from personal pronouns, which may be indicative for my variables of interest.

Comment: @Green thank you :) , just very new on this and need some sort of validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words= stopwords.words('english')
type(stop_words)
print(len(stop_words))
```

If you look at the output, type of stop words is List. then :

```
personal_pronouns= ['i', 'you', 'she', 'he', 'they'] # you can add another words for remove
for word in personal_pronouns:
    if word in stop_words:
        stop_words.remove(word)
        print(word+ '  Deleted')
print(len(stop_words))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I highly appreciate this!

Comment: @Poppy You're welcom:) if you get the answer to your question, you can accept.

Comment: also: stop_words.extend(personal_pronouns)